# How can I add a calculated column to a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df.head(6)
   City        Date      Total_Cases   Country      State
0  Autauga  2020-01-29     0             US        Alabama
1  Autauga  2020-01-30     3             US        Alabama
2  Autauga  2020-01-31     5             US        Alabama
3  Weston   2020-01-01     0             US        Wyoming
4  Weston   2020-01-02     2             US        Wyoming
5  Weston   2020-01-03     2             US        Wyoming
```

I would like to insert a new column called `New_Cases` which is today's `Total_Cases` minus `Total_Cases` from yesterday, by City/State.

```
   City        Date      Total_Cases  New_Cases  Country      State
0  Autauga  2020-01-29     0             0        US        Alabama
1  Autauga  2020-01-30     3             3        US        Alabama
2  Autauga  2020-01-31     5             2        US        Alabama
3  Weston   2020-01-01     0             0        US        Wyoming
4  Weston   2020-01-02     2             2        US        Wyoming
5  Weston   2020-01-03     2             0        US        Wyoming
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `shift` here:

```
df['New_Cases'] = df.Total_Cases - df.groupby(['City', 'State'])['Total_Cases'].shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: cool...........

Comment: I think it should be more like ``df.Total_Cases - df.groupby(["City", "State"])["Total_Cases"].shift(1).fillna(0)`` assuming the date is sorted as well

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen your code was missing the part before the minus sign which @sammywemmy added. Thank you guys so much for your help. Also another community member has referenced a similar solution in another post using diff() function